# ListenableFuture callback triggered by future cancel

Tags: java, callback, future

I am using `ListenableFuture` and register callbacks like this:

```
Futures.addCallback(
    myFuture,
    new FutureCallback<MyClass>() {

      public void onSuccess(MyClass myClass) {
        //handle success
      }
      public void onFailure(Throwable thrown) {
        //handle failure
      }
    },
    service);
```

I am wondering what is going to happen when `.cancel()` is called on that `future`. Will the `.onSuccess()` get triggered or `.onFailure()`? `.cancel()` may fail sometimes. Does that affect the callback behaviors? In general, how does the library figure out which handler to call?

Answer (score 0):

as the documentation states
here [FutureCallback](https://guava.dev/releases/23.0/api/docs/com/google/common/util/concurrent/FutureCallback.html)

void onFailure(Throwable t)

Invoked when a Future computation fails or is canceled.

If the future's get method throws an ExecutionException, then the cause is

passed to this method. Any other thrown object is passed unaltered.

---